# detect default interactive shell doesn't work on shell script

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I use zsh as the default shell, I run `echo $0` and get `-zsh` on terminal, but the following code can't detect default interactive shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
  echo "zsh"
elif [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  echo "bash"
else
  echo "others"
fi
```

The detect result is always bash, why? Thank you.

Comment: Show how you start the script.

Comment: @Cyrus run `./detect.sh`

Comment: Okay, show your shebang.

Comment: @Cyrus Sorry, I have update the shebang in code block. From your answer, I realize that shebang caused this problem. If I want to use this shebang, how can I detect it? Thank you.

Comment: @Bill : You are explicitly writing the script as a bash script. If you run it in this way, there is no other shell involved. If you would invoke it as, say, `ksh detect.sh`, it should output _others_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for detecting the *current* shell. But scripts run in their own shell, independently from the interactive shell. Your script file always runs in `bash` due to its shebang. Without the shebang, the calling shell decides how to run the script (if at all).

#### Detecting the parent shell

To detect the shell that called your script, try

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ps -p $PPID -o comm=
```

When you run an interactive `zsh` and execute this file you should get `zsh` as output.

#### Detecting the default shell

Your question's title is about detecting the *default interactive* shell. To do so, you cannot check any processes, because even if your default shell is X you can always use Y. Instead, look at the file where the default is stored:

```
grep "^$USER:" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f7
```

Comment: IIRC, if the script cannot be executed due to the lack of a shebang, `bash` will will execute the script with `bash`, not `/bin/sh`. Shebangs are not standardized, just very common.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for the comment. Seems like you are right. [Bash uses `execve`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/execute_cmd.c#L5803) which only works on binary executables and scripts starting with `#!` (see `man execve`). If `execve` cannot execute the command, bash inspects the file and may run it as a bash script itself. Up until now I thought `execve` would use `sh` if the shebang was missing. I fixed my answer.

Comment: This won't work on OSes that don't keep their user accounts in /etc/passwd (e.g. macOS).

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is with the `SHELL` environment variable:

```
echo "Your default shell is $SHELL"
```

This is defined in the POSIX standard, [section 8.3, "Other Environment Variables"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03):

> `SHELL`
> This variable shall represent a pathname of the user's preferred command language interpreter. If this interpreter does not conform to the Shell Command Language in XCU [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18), utilities may behave differently from those described in POSIX.1-2017.

Comment: This works reliably only if you set up your shell specifically to guarantee the existence of the `SHELL` variable. bash seems to do it automatically, but zsh - for instance - does not, at least not in my implementation. Of course I can set `SHELL` manually in `/etc/zshenv`. _dash_  and _ash_ don't seem to set `SHELL` either. I don't know how ksh is handling this.

Comment: @user1934428 I haven't tested extensively, but it seems to work for me in every shell under macOS (although I found it *doesn't* work right in cron jobs, because Vixie cron specifically sets `SHELL` to /bin/sh unless it's overridden in the crontab file). What environment are you using?

Comment: On the Mac, this is nearly correct (perhaps the BSD builds of the shells are different from Linux, or Mac provides by default the respective settings in /etc/...)  One case where it does **not** work on MacOS either (at least for me), is to start a bash login shell, and within this, open a non-login  zsh subshell. In this case, `SHELL` would still show _bash_, although we are by now in zsh.

Comment: @user1934428 That's what it should do -- `$SHELL` should be the shell set for the current user in the user database (/etc/passwd on traditional unixes, /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users on macOS). You can test this by changing the shell in Terminal.app's preferences from "Default login shell" to something else. `$SHELL` should still show the user's default shell, not the something else you chose in the Terminal prefs.

Comment: I see that I misread the OPs question: He wanted to know the default login shell for the user, not the shell he is currently using. Thank you for pointing this out!